# Why does the "API" tag still exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

A short while ago, during a Suggested Edits review, I came across a post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595745/how-to-include-pylon-api-in-cmakelists)) where the `api` tag had been added (with no other changes or improvements).

Now, as has become my habit, in 'tag' edits for a tag with which I am unfamiliar, I generally hover on that added/removed tag to see what it *really* should be used for. In this case, the short answer was, "DO NOT USE … { plus some other stuff - you can easily find out for yourselves}" Needless to say, I chose "Reject" with "Irrelevant Tags" as the reason!

However, if this tag should not be used, why does it exist? Is it a test? (Or a paranoia trap?)

Comment: As long as a tag is used it won't be deleted. As long as a tag is not blacklisted it can be recreated. Creating a tag is as simple as one person having enough reputation and [applying it to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).